# Extract value via OSX Terminal from .html for "curl" submission within a single script

Tags: macos, bash, curl

How do I extract the variable value of the following line of an html page via Terminal to submit it afterwards via "curl -d" in the same script?

```
     <input type="hidden" name="au_pxytimetag" value="1234567890">
```

Edit: how do I transfer the extracted value to the "curl -d" command within a single script? might be a silly question, but I'm total noob. =0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

I cannot tell from your question what you are actually trying to do. I originally thought you were trying to extract a variable from a file, but it seems you actually want to firstly, get that file, secondly extract a variable, and thirdly, use variable for something else... so let's address each of those steps:

Firstly you want to grab a page using `curl`, so you will do

```
curl www.some.where.com
```

and the page will be output on your terminal. But actually you want to search for something on that page, so you need to do

```
curl www.some.where.com | awk something
```

or

```
curl www.some.where.com | grep something
```

But you want to put that into a variable, so you need to do

```
var=$(curl www.some.where.com | awk something)
```

or

```
var=$(curl www.some.where.com | grep something)
```

The actual command I think you want is

```
var=$(curl www.some.where.com | awk -F\" '/au_pxytimetag/{print $(NF-1)}')
```

Then you want to use the variable `var` for another `curl` operation, so you will need to do

```
curl -d "param1=$var" http://some.url.com/somewhere
```

**Original answer**

I'd use `awk` like this:

```
var=$(awk -F\" '/au_pxytimetag/{print $(NF-1)}' yourfile)
```

to take second to last field on line containing `au_pxytimetag` using `"` as field separator.

Then you can use it like this

```
curl -d "param1=$var&param2=SomethingElse" http://some.url.com/somewhere
```

Comment: it works when i use a local html file, but both your and @Herson 's command cannot find the file when it is accessed through http:// (awk: can't open file)(grep: http: //b.l.a.h.html: No such file or directory) any ideas?

Comment: the answer to my comment is var=$(curl http://auth.address/login.html | awk -F\" '/au_pxytimetag/{print $(NF-1)}')

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
grep au_pxytimetag input.html | sed "s/.* value=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/"
```

EDIT:

If you need this on a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA=$(grep au_pxytimetag input.html | sed "s/.* value=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/")
curl http://example.com -d $DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xmllint`:

```
value=$(xmllint --html --xpath "string(//input[@name='au_pxytimetag']/@value)" index.html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
 xidel http://webpage -e "//input[@name='au_pxytimetag']/@value"
```

But you do not need to.

With

```
 xidel http://webpage -f "(//form)[1]" -e "//what-you-need-from-the-next-page"
```

you can send all values from the first form on the webpage to the form action and then you can query something from the next page